# Sharepoint 2016 list update with CSV

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, powershell, import, csv

I am stuck with an import to a SharePoint List from CSV.
The goal is to update only certain columns according to the value of another column.

IE:
If Colum A has value X then update Colum B and get the value from CSV.
Whereas the colum-names from Sharepoint List and CSV differ.

I came up with 2 similar solutions but they do not update the list.

```
$delimeter = ";"
$filePath = "D:\Temp\test.csv"
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path $filepath -Delimiter $delimeter

$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "URL"
$list = $web.Lists["testlist"]

$owner = "test"
$costcenter = "costcenter"

#$web = Get-SPWeb $web
#$lists = $web.Lists[$list]

Write-Host
Write-Host
Write-Host

$items = $list.Items

foreach ($line in $CSVData)
{ 
    foreach($item in $items)
    {        
        if($item[$owner] -eq $line.'UsEMail')
        {
           $item[$costcenter] = $line.UsAccountNum
            $item.Update();        
        }
     }
}
```

```
# Load in the CSV
$delimeter = ";"
$filePath = "D:\Temp\test.csv"
$csvData = Import-Csv $filePath -Delimiter $delimeter

# SharePoint column names
$moneyColumn = "costcenter"
$customerNoColumn = "test"

# Get SharePoint list
$web = Get-SPWeb "URL"
$list = $web.Lists["testlist"]

# Loop through each line in the CSV file
foreach ($line in $csvData)
{
    # Get item matching $customerNo
    $customerItem = $list.Items | Where $_.$customerNoColumn -eq $line.UsEMail
    #$customerItem = $list.Items | Where $_.$customerNoColumn -eq $line.$UsEMail
    #$customerItem = $list.Items | Where $customerNoColumn -eq $line.UsEMail

    if ($customerItem -ne $null)
    {
        if ($customerItem[$moneyColumn] -ne $line.UsAccountNum)
        {
            $customerItem[$moneyColumn] = $line.UsAccountNum
            $customerItem.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas.

Regards

Fischer

Comment: Your examples are really confusing. How does your CSV look like?

Comment: Hi Christoffer The CSV has a header separated by semicolon. The CSV has about 10 different columns. Whereas two are important. One that is compared with the colum of Sharepoint List. And if the value of the CSV-colum has a match, then another colum on the CSV with the value is taken to update also another colum in the Sharepoint List

Comment: Example CSV
Header -> h1;h2;h3;h4;h5
Values -> A;B;C;D;E

Example Sharepoint List:
Columnames -> Name;City;Street;Zip-Code;Country

Comment: Example CSV
Header -> h1;h2;h3;h4;h5
Values -> A;NY;C;D;USA

Example Sharepoint List:
Columnames -> Name;City;Street;Zip-Code;Country
Values -> Jones;NY;5th;10001;CH

Scripts looks in CSV for h2 if it finds matching value in Sharepoint List in Columname City then updates the value from CSV h5 to the Sharepoint List in Columname "Country" to the value USA.

Hope this clears the confusion
Thank you
Fischer